# Cannot read property ‘concat’ of undefined when inserting new child into recursive Polymer component

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I’m having trouble with a recursive Polymer component that has a button for inserting new elements into itself. It has `add` links for inserting elements. They work when clicked on elements I define initially, but fail for elements that are inserted by the add — I get an error `Cannot read property ‘concat’ of undefined`.

To trigger the error, click any `add` link, which will succeed in inserting a node, and then click `add` again on the node that was inserted. This will fail with the error.

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js?20150925"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/4c94736fac6681e84ec8c00da53484c5d3c2226b/polymer.html">

<template is="dom-bind">
  <test-insert></test-insert>
</template>
 
<dom-module id="test-insert">
  <template>
    <test-recurse object="[[_object]]"></test-recurse>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="test-recurse">
  <template>
    <style>
      a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 1em;}
    </style>
    Label: <span>[[object.label]]</span>   <a on-click="_pushNewElement">add</a>

    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[object.children]]">
        <li><test-recurse object="[[item]]"></test-recurse></li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function () {
  Polymer({
    is: 'test-insert',
    properties: {
      _object: Object
    },

    ready: function () {
      this._object = {
        label: 'a1', 
        children: [
          { label: 'b1', children: [] }, 
          { label: 'b2', children: [{label: 'c1', children: []}] }
        ]
      };
    }
  });

  var count = 0;
  Polymer({
    is: 'test-recurse',
    properties: {
      object: Object
    },
    _pushNewElement: function () {
      var newLabel = {label: 'Object ' + (++count)};
      console.log({newLabel: newLabel}, '_pushNewElement');
      this.object.children = this.object.children || [];
      this.unshift('object.children', newLabel);
    }
  });
}());
</script>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to fix one line:

```
this.set('object.children', this.object.children || []);
```

The `children` array wasn't being created properly.

Comment: Thanks @ricky! Your answer helps me understand better how Polymer property registration works. After implementing your answer (which does solve the problem), I realized that if I ensure the object has children before I push it to the binding, I can avoid having to explicitly tell Polymer about the children array:

`var newLabel = {label: 'Object ' + (++count), children: []};` 

(Inserting **children: []**.) Just noting this in case others find it helpful.

Comment: No problem! Yes, that would definitely work as well and is a cleaner approach. Cheers.